# Prove that center of circle and point of intersection of circle and x axis will have same X-coordinate.

Tags: proof-writing, proof-explanation, circles

My question is:

> How can I prove if a circle, which have center say $(c,0)$,
> **touching** (not **cutting**) X-Axis at some point will have same X-coordinate of center and X-Axis: $c$?

Let me explain the question. You may know that equation of a circle passing through X-Axis is given by:

$$
x^{2}+y^{2}-2 h x-2 a y+h^{2}=0
$$
Where $h$ are coordinate of circle and $a$ is radius.

Derivation of this general equation is given as following:

> Consider a point $C(h,k)$ as center of a circle and touching the
> X-Axis at point $M$.

Diagram:
[image]!

> Now $M$ has Y-coordinate 0 since it is on X-Axis. And X-coordinate $h$
> (why? this is my question)
>
> So now we have two points $C(h,k)$ and $M(h,0)$. The distance between
> these two points will be radius (say $a$) of the circle.
>
> So  $$a^{2}=(h-h)^{2}+(0-k)^{2}$$ $$\Rightarrow a^{2}=k^{2}$$
> $$\Rightarrow \quad a=k$$
>
> Hence on putting values in general equation of circle ie,
>
> \begin{align} (x-h)^{2}+(y-k)^{2}=r^{2} \end{align}
>
> We get: $$ \begin{aligned} &\Longrightarrow x^{2}+h^{2}-2 h
>  x+y^{2}+a^{2}-2 a y=a^{2}\\ &\Longrightarrow x^{2}+y^{2}-2 h x-2 a
> y+h^{2}+a^{2}-a^{2}=0\\ &\Longrightarrow x^{2}+y^{2}-2 h x-2 a y+h^{2}+a^{2}-a^{2}=0\\ &\Longrightarrow x^{2}+y^{2}-2 h x-2 a
> y+h^{2}=0 \end{aligned} $$

My question is How can we be so sure that X-coordinate of center and point on X-Axis will always be same?
I mean if we are assuming them to be equal in derivation of a general equation then both must be same in all cases. But why? How can I prove that both center and X-Axis will have same X-coordinate?

Comment: The $x$-axis is a tangent to the circle, so it is normal to the radius at the point of contact. Hence the centre and the point of contact have the same $x$-coordinate.

Comment: There is no $k$ in your first equation.

Comment: @JeanMarie thanks! Edited it.

Comment: Please try to make the titles of your questions more informative. For example, *Why does $a<b$ imply $a+c<b+c$?* is much more useful for other users than *A question about inequality.* From [How can I ask a good question?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/589/): *Make your title as descriptive as possible. In many cases one can actually phrase the title as the question, at least in such a way so as to be comprehensible to an expert reader.* You can find more tips for choosing a good title [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10144/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple geometry is a lot easier than algebra in this case. The $x$-axis is tangent to the circle, so the radius at the point of contact is perpendicular to the $x$-axis. Hence the centre and the point of contact have the same $x$-coordinate.

Answer (score 1):

Note that the $x$-coordinate of the touching point is the intersection of the circle and the $x$-axis. So, solve the system of equations below
$$
x^{2}+y^{2}-2 h x-2 a y+h^{2}=0,\>\>\>\>\>y=0
$$

to get

$$(x-h)^2=0$$

Thus, $x=h$, which is just  the $x$-coordinate of the center.